# Issues with resources generated by react in Android Studio 3

Tags: android, gradle, react-native, android-studio-3.0, code-push

I recently upgraded to Android Studio 3

```
gradle plugin: 3.0.0-beta2
gradle: 4.1
```

In our project we use: "react-native": "0.46.4" with the **codepush plugin**.

Building:

```
gradlew assembleStagingDebug
```

works just fine, but as soon as I try to build production:

```
gradlew assembleProductionRelease
```

I get an error caused by resources that are created by react in the processProductinoReleaseResources task:

```
Issues:
 - ERROR: /Users/user/react/android/app/build/intermediates/res/merged/production/release/drawable-hdpi/node_modules_reactnavigation_src_views_assets_backicon.png uncompiled PNG file passed as argument. Must be compiled first into .flat file.
 - ERROR:  failed parsing overlays
        at com.android.builder.internal.aapt.v2.AaptV2Jni.buildException(AaptV2Jni.java:154)
```

In my conquest against this issue I tried it with disabling proguard like:

```
buildTypes {
        release {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            shrinkResources false
        }
        debug {
            debuggable true
            minifyEnabled false
            println proguardFiles
        }
    }
```

But without any luck.

Any ideas? I would also appreciate an explanation of where this .flat conversion of the android resources happens what it actually does and why it does not happen during the StagingDebug task.

The workaround presented [here](https://github.com/react-community/react-navigation/issues/1976) worked for me in the end. But the original issue persists i think.

***update 28.3.2018*** Since Android studio 3.1 upgrade I get this:

```
WARNING: The option 'android.enableAapt2' is deprecated and should not be used anymore. Use 'android.enableAapt2=true' to remove this warning. It will be removed at the end of 2018
```

Since the issues on the react page are closed, I am looking for alternatives before they deprecate that workaround.

Answer (score 17):

In your gradle.properties file add following lines:

```
classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'
distributionUrl=https://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-4.1-all.zip
android.enableAapt2=false
```

Comment: Yes that what worked for me too, but I still think there is a bug in react and it should work without this property flag.

Comment: The only thing this does for me is change the error into `Original is here. The version qualifier may be implied.`

Comment: @Kevin Østerkilde Did you also have following in your project's build.gradle
    dependencies {
        
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0'

    }

Comment: @user7532779 I did, yes.

Actually I managed to solve my issue earlier today and I'm not sure if it's even related. I deleted any folders in `android/app/src/main/res` that started with `drawable`, as well as deleted `android/app/src/main/assets/index.bundle`.

After that, running `./gradlew assembleRelease` just worked. (Still with the fixes mentioned here applied.)

Comment: Hmmm it works but I don't know why :P I just added `android.enableAapt2=false` and in started working ... my `gradle.properties` file already has `android.useDeprecatedNdk=true` and `RELEASE_STORE_FILE` info.

Comment: `enableAapt2` is deprecated

Answer (score 3):

In my case adding `android.enableAapt2=false` to gradle.properties was enough to fix this.

**[UPDATE]** This is indeed depreciated. So you might want to try another solution.

Comment: That is true, but it seems this workaround will come to an end because since Android Studio 3.1 it is deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to replace `compile` with `implementation`

Modify `app/build.gradle` to be:

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation "com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue in my app. It is resolved by 
Go to "Android" directory and run

```
gradlew clean
```